# Sort list by frequency but keeping original order when given same frequency

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, collections, frequency

This is for a practice website that has stumped me (checkio). I need to create a function that takes a list and sorts it by frequency (most -> least). No problem, but my issue is that is also needs to retain the original order of the list when presented with elements that have the same frequency.

See below.

```
import collections
from collections import Counter
def frequency_sort(items):
  if len(items) > 0:
    counts = collections.Counter(items)
    print(sorted(items, key=lambda x: (counts[x], x), reverse=True))
  else:
    print([])  

if __name__ == '__main__':

    (frequency_sort([4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4])) == [4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 2, 2]
    (frequency_sort(['bob', 'bob', 'carl', 'alex', 'bob'])) == ['bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'carl', 'alex']
    (frequency_sort([17, 99, 42])) == [17, 99, 42]
    (frequency_sort([])) == []
    (frequency_sort([1])) == [1]
```

Number 3 has the bad output, "[17, 42, 99]". 
I'm pretty lost in how to solve this one.

Answer (score 0):

> when presented with elements that have the same frequency

If you mean by that that **all** the element if the list appear at the same frequency, try to add this check before sorting the list.

```
def frequency_sort(items):
  if len(items) > 0:
    counts = collections.Counter(items)
    if len(set(counts.values())) > 1:
        print(sorted(items, key=lambda x: (counts[x], x), reverse=True))
    else:
        print(items)
  else:
    print([])
```

Gathering all the different `counts` values into one `set` will discard any duplicates frequencies, then you can ask how many different frequencies you have. If just *1* return the original list otherwise sort it.

This will results with:

```
>>> frequency_sort([17, 99, 42])
[17, 99, 42]
```

Comment: Sadly I already tried this type of solution and it doesn't work- one of the checks that the function is run against is "frequency_sort([1, 2, 2, 1]) == [1,1,2,2]" and this function fails that check. I guess that it doesn't work when there are multiple elements with the same multiple frequency.

Comment: According to the quote from the original problem and the **all** statement in my solution the results in the case of`[1, 2, 2, 1]` should be "retain the original order" due to the fact that "elements that have the same frequency".
I'm missing something here?